# python maya - Select children 'nurbs' then hides key

Tags: python, maya

The script below selects all the child nurbCurves of the selected object. The issue I'm having is that after running the script, none of the keys from the children nodes appear in the timeline. Why is that? How can I correct this?

To test the script. Create a few nurb curve controls and animate the position. Then parent them together so their parent is the same master control. Then select the main control and run the script.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Get selected objects
curSel = maya.cmds.ls(sl=True)

# Or, you can also specify a type in the listRelatives command
nurbsNodes = maya.cmds.listRelatives(curSel, allDescendents=True, noIntermediate=True, fullPath=True, type="nurbsCurve", path=True)

cmds.select(nurbsNodes)
```

Comment: If you select them yourself from the outliner, do you see the keyframes?

Comment: Yeah that's what I don't understand. When I run this script it for some reason doesn't highlight the objects in the outline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting the `nurbsCurve` *shapes*, but your animation is on the *transform*

```
# list the shape nodes
nurbsShapes = maya.cmds.listRelatives(curSel, allDescendents=True, noIntermediate=True, fullPath=True, type="nurbsCurve", path=True)
# list the transform nodes to each shape node
nurbsTransforms = maya.cmds.listRelatives(nurbsShapes, type='transform', parent=True)
# select the transform nodes
cmds.select(nurbsTransforms)
```